# tableview.reloaddata() fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

Custom'ная таблица **из 4-х ячеек**, у каждой ячейке свой `identifire`. Есть кнопка на ячейке "Изменить" после нажатия я изменяю  `identifire`. И чтоб все работало надо перезагрузить таблицу.

Из класса `UITableViewCell` обращаюсь к классу `UITableViewController` и вызываю метод `tableView.reloadData`

```
@IBAction func changeBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {

    CategoryGoodsActivity().changeFlagString("edit")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        CategoryGoodsActivity().reloadTable()
    })

}
```

а вот метод в `UITableViewController` :

```
func reloadTable()  {
        tableView.reloadData()
}

CategoryGoodsActivity - это UITableViewController
```

Запускаю проект есть таблица с ячейкой, в ячейке есть кнопка "изменить" нажимаю на эту кнопку проект падает и выдает эту ошибку

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

`delegate` и `datasource` у таблицы вызываю.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя пустой указатель tableView. Проверь его (выведи в лог, например). И проверь сторибоард или то место, где ты таблицу создаешь и связываешь.